# pgfplots: Placing nodes to the right of scatter plot markers at fixed x-position

Tags: pgfplots, nodes

I would like to create a scatter plot with pgfplots, in which a text node is placed for every marker. The nodes should be at the same y-value of the respective marker, but at a fixed x-coordinate. The nodes' content should be the corresponding value from the 'label' column of the data table.

The MWE shows how far I could get:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{filecontents*}{exp1.txt}
x   y   label
0.33246562684995834 -1  0.33247(5)
0.33284098219518293 -2  0.33284(5)
0.3319866331064203  -3  0.33199(5)
0.33301936261400417 -4  0.33302(5)
0.3343605877669449  -5  0.33436(5)
0.33419390169962254 -6  0.33419(5)
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xmin=0.331, xmax=0.339, ytick=data,
    visualization depends on={value \thisrow{label} \as \labela},
    nodes near coords={\labela},
    nodes near coords align={horizontal}]
    \addplot+[scatter, only marks] table[x=x,y=y] {exp1.txt};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

So the question is: How can I 'detach' the x-coordinates of the text nodes from the markers and align all of them to the right of a given x-value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There might be more elegant ways of doing this, but this works at least. See some comments in the code.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{filecontents*}{exp1.txt}
x   y   label
0.33246562684995834 -1  0.33247(5)
0.33284098219518293 -2  0.33284(5)
0.3319866331064203  -3  0.33199(5)
0.33301936261400417 -4  0.33302(5)
0.3343605877669449  -5  0.33436(5)
0.33419390169962254 -6  0.33419(5)
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xmin=0.331, xmax=0.339, ytick=data,
    visualization depends on={value \thisrow{label} \as \labela},,
    nodes near coords align={horizontal},
    xticklabel style={/pgf/number format/precision=3} % the xticklabels were duplicated
]
    % plot only the dots
    \addplot+[only marks] table[x=x,y=y] {exp1.txt};
    % use x expr to set a fixed x-value, and set mark=none to only get the node near coord
    \addplot [nodes near coords={\labela}, only marks,mark=none] table[x expr=0.338,y=y] {exp1.txt};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```